# Audio Card Cirrus Logic CS8409 on Ubuntu 21.10 iMac19,2 not recognized

Tags: sound, mac

I've looked through some of the snd-hda-intel kernel module notes and it looks like patches have been added to the kernel to support CS8409.  However, Ubuntu 21.10 doesn't even recognize the card now.  See below:

```
cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec

Codec: Cirrus Logic CS8409
Codec: ATI R6xx HDMI

aplay -l


**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Has anyone else got this sound card to work on an iMac19,2?
Is there a better forum to ask this question?

Comment: I know this thread is a little old, but have a look at this https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro/issues/11

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like it could be coming.  I'm looking forward to 22.04 :)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into trying Pop!_OS on my iMac, supposedly kernel 5.15 (or higher) that was released a couple of weeks ago has a bunch of fixes for CS8409. I haven't tried it myself yet though so don't know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've try pop os 21.10 with 5.15 kernel and it not work, i've tried many fedora rawhide 5.15 dev version during his développement and it's seems, no sound, but when 5.15 stable is release, there's a difference, compare to 5.15 RC versions where the output and it put been display on "headpod output" and "speaker output", and on stable just no any output or "dummy output" and sound stiil not working, I think it's a probleme with the new audio module "Pipewire", until this moment i would try some non-official patches and wait with unwaiting the Ubuntu 22.04 for this evil audio >:(

(I'm on iMac 2017 all Intel with the Intel HDA sound and Cirrus Logic CS8409 soudn card)

Comment: Edit : this driver make sound perfectly work on debian distros' : https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro but microphone not work